# change magento 2.1.6 to 2.1.0

Tags: magento2, theme, upgrade, version, static-content-deploy

Is it possible my magento 2.1.6 to magento 2.1.0 because my magento theme only support max version magento 2.1.0 that's why my theme products and some pages css and js not working and also every time run the deploy command it shows 12 errors.
Any one let me help I tried that magento 2.1.6 to 2.1.0 it is shows some errors.

Comment: How's the errors look like? And, it it possible to upgrade the theme first? I don't recommend you to downgrade Magento version.

Comment: I m not interest to downgrade but in magento 2.1.6 the theme css and js not  working properly I try to install patch file but it is not installing. Then I find the theme in themeforest what version it magento support it shows magento 1.9.0.0 to 2.1.0 only that's why I downgrade. The error is [Exception]
  Warning: file_get_contents(/home/auzmind/public_html/var/di/setup.ser): fai
  led to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/auzmind/public_html/
  vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManager/ConfigLoader/Compiled.php on line 28

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather fix the theme. I don't think Magento supports downgrading currently.
You can try to change the composer required version and then run composer update.
Maybe it works? I wouldn't bet on it though.

> composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.1.0 --no-update
>
> composer update

Comment: This is I am tryed to downgrade it is update successfully but it shows error [Exception]
  Warning: file_get_contents(/home/auzmind/public_html/var/di/setup.ser): fai
  led to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/auzmind/public_html/
  vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManager/ConfigLoader/Compiled.php on lin
  e 28

Comment: did you recompile di? `bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Comment: yes tried all commands both upgrade and static-content:deploy commands only shows error

Comment: you need to get your information straight or you won't get any help. post all information, errors and such.

Comment: How about remove `var/di` folder then re-run `bin/magento setup:di:compile`?